What LLM AI model is the easiest one to install locally in docker without needing an external API?
There are several LLMs that seem to have not only open source, but also open models.
I want to spin-up a docker to provide me with an API so I can programmatically query and get responses.
I've heard of Llama, Mixtral, and so on and so on.
I've also seen this humongous list: https://github.com/eugeneyan/open-llms but I don't know really how to process this page. From the title it seems they all should have open models. But I can't believe there are so many models already released. Or are there?
Same with this list... https://github.com/Hannibal046/Awesome-LLM large listing but IDK how to process that many information.
It also seems (maybe I'm wrong) that for Llama you don't just download the model, you need to register and make a request that maybe someone approves or something like this.
I wonder what's the LLM AI that I can just spin up doing docker run -p xxx:xxx llm-image optionally with a volume pointing to the model, that is the "easier to get it running" in a regular laptop.
I'm not expecting the most intelligent, nor the most powerful, nor the one with the widest token-window...
I just want to have some AI that is open-model as well as open-source to play around.
Requirements:

Open model, downloadable without manual approvals intervention.
Runnable inside docker inside a local laptop.
The laptop has 1TB disk space. I wonder how big are the model files.

Initially a regular standard pre-trained english+spanish general purpose model is okey. But what I want to learn to do is "feed it with documents from my company" so I can ask it things about my company and the AI get responses. But this is next step. Now: just to play and learn with "fully local AI".
